# Where do microcontrollers related questions belong?

Tags: support

Sometimes I don't know what to do with MCU related questions.

On one hand, they are about programming, on the other hand, they are more or less hardware related, so maybe they belong to electronics SE.

What if the question is about registers, sensors, optimization? Some problems have both hardware and code solutions (like syncing two sensors). Is it OK to post such question on both sites?

Comment: MCU? [What?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCU) Please be a little more specific. Don't assume everyone knows what abbreviation you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry, updated. I hadn't a clue that MCU is also a Japanese hip-hop/rap artist.

Comment: Or, arguably more significant, the Marvel Cinematic Universe :D

Comment: Yes. Now I need some superhero who will answer it, because next year I'm gonna dive into MCU realm.

Comment: Embedded Systems beta has been killed recently, so your best bet is on Electronics...

Comment: _"Is it OK to post such question on both sites?"_ No. Cross posting is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as programming related questions about microcontrollers go, most questions would be on-topic for either Stack Overflow or [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Cross posting isn't allowed, so if your question is on-topic on both sites, pick one or the either.

On Stack Overflow questions about code that accesses hardware are on-topic, but not questions about the hardware itself. Questions about software development tools are also on-topic here.

So questions on the following topics are on-topic on Stack Overflow:

- code that accesses microcontroller hardware and connected devices
- microcontroller specific assembly language instructions and directives
- C language extensions for microcontrollers
- software development tools, such as compilers, assemblers and IDEs, targeting microcontrollers

Questions on the following topics are off-topic on Stack Overflow:

- layout and connections between devices
- electrical, thermal, and physical characteristics of devices
- component alternatives

My understanding that all these topics, both software and hardware, are allowed on Electrical Engineering, but I don't follow that site very closely. Check that site's [tour page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any questions there.

Note that open ended recommendation/shopping questions like "What what hardware should I buy?" or "What software development tool should I use?" are off-topic on both sites, and most sites in the Stack Exchange network generally. Also programming questions, especially those involving C/C++, that have little to do with microcontrollers other than the fact the code happens to be running on one, are likely to be considered off-topic on Electrical Engineering.

Given a choice between the two sites I would choose Electrical Engineering. Based the amount of microcontroller traffic on each site, your questions would be more likely to be answered there.

Answer (score 6):

I've already asked software questions in StackOverflow and been redirected to SuperUser.

So IMHO, question location should not be based on the "support" but on the question content.

Maybe a small analysis will prove that's a initially software question is in fact hardware related, but then it becomes another question (with more details thanks to the software answers).

Do not cross post. Ever.

Comment: Well done. For a newbie...

Comment: Thanks (including for the edit) !